# SQL EXEC PROCEDURE: "Must declare the scalar variable "@p1"

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2014

I am getting the following error when I try to execute the stored procedure below:

`Must declare the scalar variable "@p1"`

I don't understand why or how to fix, any help would be appreciated. thanKs

**Stored procedure:**

```
USE [SERVER_NAME]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[APP_jdtest_shp_0]    Script Date: 16/12/2019 11:13:01 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[jdtest_shp_0] 
    @p1 nvarchar(100),  
    @n nvarchar(100) 
AS 
EXEC('
    CREATE VIEW dbo.[' + @n + '] AS 
    SELECT 
        RTRIM([F].[F_CODE]) As F_UID ,  
        RTRIM([TP].[F_TP_NAME]) As F_TP_UID ,  
        RTRIM([NS].[F_CODE]) AS F_CODE,  
        RTRIM([NS].[SOME_DATE]) AS SOME_DATE,  
        RTRIM([NS].[ANOTHER_DATE]) AS ANOTHER_DATE,  
        RTRIM([NS].[SPD]) AS SPD,  
        RTRIM([NS].[LK_DATE]) AS LK_DATE,  
        RTRIM([NS].[RC_DATE]) AS RC_DATE,  
        RTRIM([NS].[RD_DATE]) AS RD_DATE,  
        RTRIM([NS].[OLD_UID]) AS OLD_UID,  
        RTRIM([NS].[VN]) AS VN,  
        RTRIM([NS].[R_I]) AS R_I,  
        RTRIM([NS].[WTU_UID]) AS WTU_UID,  
        RTRIM([NS].[D_LT]) AS D_LT,  
        RTRIM([PLT_UD].[PLT]) As L_A_PLT_UD_UID ,  
        RTRIM([RT].[RT_NAME]) As RT_UID ,  
        RTRIM([SS].[S_S_NAME]) As S_S_UID ,  
        RTRIM([NS].[S_DATE]) AS S_DATE,  
        RTRIM([SUR].[S_SUR_NAME]) As S_SUR_UID ,  
        RTRIM([NS].[S_TOL]) AS S_TOL,  
        RTRIM([LKP_AUTH].[AUTH_NAME]) As AUTH_UID ,  
        [NS].[S_G] AS S_G,  
        RTRIM([NS].[NS_UID]) AS NS_UID,  
        RTRIM([NSG_C].[C_NAME]) As C_UID ,  
        RTRIM([NS].[CLT]) AS CLT,  
        RTRIM([NS].[ONR_UID]) AS ONR_UID,  
        RTRIM([NC].[S_CLF_NAME]) As S_CLF_UID , 
        RTRIM([NS].[XP]) AS XP,  
        RTRIM([NS].[CSTART_X]) AS CSTART_X,  
        RTRIM([NS].[CSTART_Y]) AS CSTART_Y,  
        RTRIM([NS].[CEND_X]) AS CEND_X,  
        RTRIM([NS].[CEND_Y]) AS CEND_Y 
    FROM NS  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN F ON NS.F_UID = F.F_UID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FT ON NS.F_TP_UID = FT.FT_UID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PLT_UD ON NS.L_A_PLT_UD_UID = SEC_PLT_UD.PLT_UD_UID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RT ON NS.RT_UID = RT.RT_UID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN STT ON NS.S_S_UID = SS.S_S_UID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SUR ON NS.S_SUR_UID = SUR.S_SUR_UID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AUTH ON NS.AUTH_UID = AUTH.AUTH_UID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON NS.C_UID = C.C_UID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN NSC ON NS.S_CLF_UID = NSC.S_CLF_UID 
WHERE  
    ([NS].[SHAPE_GEOMETRY].STIntersects(Geometry::STGeomFromText(' + '@p1' + ', 0).MakeValid())>0) AND  
    ([NS].[S_G].STGeometryTP() = ''POINT'')  '
)
```

EDIT: using sql server 2014. This is not my code, I am trying to fix a bug in someone else's code.

**UPDATE:** updated the 'execute command' section to show how the procedure is being executed

Comment: Using formatting in your dynamic SQL to be readable is *just as important* as formatting your non-dynamic SQL.

Comment: You have an answer that shows you the **correct** way to do things. But the problem with your code would be evident if you simply selected the string that you generate as output for debugging purposes. You would then notice that you simply embedded the name of your parameter in your query - when you meant to embed the value contained in the string. If you want to write dynamic sql, you must be able to see the generated code to debug it.

Comment: And it is more than a little strange that you need a stored procedure to create a very, **VERY** specific view. More importantly, sql server 2008 is now completely unsupported; someone should be concerned about this.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot we updated to sql server 2014 a few weeks ago. This is also not my code but someone else's, I am just trying to fix the bug.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to generate a view over and over and over like this in the first place. Why not either a procedure that receives @p1 or a view and use a where clause when selecting from it? Generating view after view of the same thing with only a slight change to the where predicate indicates a design problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `sp_executesql` instead of `EXEC()` if you want to use parameters in your dynamic statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[123456] 
    @p1 nvarchar(100),  
    @n nvarchar(100) 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @err int

    SET @stm = 
        N'CREATE VIEW dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@n) + N' AS ' +
        N'SELECT 
            RTRIM([FEATURE].[FEATURE_CODE]) As FEATURE_UID ,  
            RTRIM([FEATURE_TYPE].[FEATURE_TYPE_NAME]) As FEATURE_TYPE_UID ,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[FEATURE_CODE]) AS FEATURE_CODE,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[START_DATE]) AS START_DATE,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[END_DATE]) AS END_DATE,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[SUSPEND_ACTIVITIES]) AS SUSPEND_ACTIVITIES,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[RECORD_ENTRY_DATE]) AS RECORD_ENTRY_DATE,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[RECORD_CHANGE_DATE]) AS RECORD_CHANGE_DATE,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[RECORD_DELETE_DATE]) AS RECORD_DELETE_DATE,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[OLD_SYSTEM_UID]) AS OLD_SYSTEM_UID,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[VERSION_NUMBER]) AS VERSION_NUMBER,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[RECORD_IDENTIFIER]) AS RECORD_IDENTIFIER,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[WARD_UID]) AS WARD_UID,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[DIGITAL_LENGTH]) AS DIGITAL_LENGTH,  
            RTRIM([SEC_USER].[USER_NAME]) As LAST_EDIT_USER_UID ,  
            RTRIM([LKP_RECORD_TYPE].[RECORD_TYPE_NAME]) As RECORD_TYPE_UID ,  
            RTRIM([LKP_STREET_STATE].[STREET_STATE_NAME]) As STREET_STATE_UID ,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[STATE_DATE]) AS STATE_DATE,  
            RTRIM([LKP_STREET_SURFACE].[STREET_SURFACE_NAME]) As STREET_SURFACE_UID ,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[STREET_TOLERANCE]) AS STREET_TOLERANCE,  
            RTRIM([LKP_AUTHORITY].[AUTHORITY_NAME]) As AUTHORITY_UID ,  
            [NSG_STREETS].[SHAPE_GEOGRAPHY] AS SHAPE_GEOGRAPHY,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[NSG_STREETS_UID]) AS NSG_STREETS_UID,  
            RTRIM([NSG_COUNTY].[COUNTY_NAME]) As COUNTY_UID ,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[CLASS_UID]) AS CLASS_UID,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[OWNER_UID]) AS OWNER_UID,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREET_CLASSIFICATION].[STREET_CLASSIFICATION_NAME]) As STREET_CLASSIFICATION_UID ,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[EXPORT]) AS EXPORT,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[CSTART_X]) AS CSTART_X,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[CSTART_Y]) AS CSTART_Y,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[CEND_X]) AS CEND_X,  
            RTRIM([NSG_STREETS].[CEND_Y]) AS CEND_Y FROM NSG_STREETS  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN FEATURE ON NSG_STREETS.FEATURE_UID = FEATURE.FEATURE_UID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN FEATURE_TYPE ON NSG_STREETS.FEATURE_TYPE_UID = FEATURE_TYPE.FEATURE_TYPE_UID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SEC_USER ON NSG_STREETS.LAST_EDIT_USER_UID = SEC_USER.USER_UID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LKP_RECORD_TYPE ON NSG_STREETS.RECORD_TYPE_UID = LKP_RECORD_TYPE.RECORD_TYPE_UID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LKP_STREET_STATE ON NSG_STREETS.STREET_STATE_UID = LKP_STREET_STATE.STREET_STATE_UID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LKP_STREET_SURFACE ON NSG_STREETS.STREET_SURFACE_UID = LKP_STREET_SURFACE.STREET_SURFACE_UID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LKP_AUTHORITY ON NSG_STREETS.AUTHORITY_UID = LKP_AUTHORITY.AUTHORITY_UID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN NSG_COUNTY ON NSG_STREETS.COUNTY_UID = NSG_COUNTY.COUNTY_UID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN NSG_STREET_CLASSIFICATION ON NSG_STREETS.STREET_CLASSIFICATION_UID = NSG_STREET_CLASSIFICATION.STREET_CLASSIFICATION_UID 
        WHERE  
            ([NSG_STREETS].[SHAPE_GEOMETRY].STIntersects(Geometry::STGeomFromText(@p1, 0).MakeValid())>0) AND  
            ([NSG_STREETS].[SHAPE_GEOGRAPHY].STGeometryType() = ''POINT'')  '

    EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm, N'@p1 nvarchar(100)', @p1

    IF @err <> 0 BEGIN
        PRINT 'Error'
        RETURN @err
    END
END
```

Comment: `'dbo.[' + @n + '] AS '` should be `N'dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@n) + N' AS '`. otherwise this is just an injection issue waiting to be exploited.

Comment: Thanks, @Larnu, injection issues are always important.